React Components not showing on server
I'm at the very beginning in React and I'm wondering why the components aren't loading.. Beforehand I've used some outdated code, which I'm not sure I got rid of entirely.
Repo: https://github.com/04lex/alex-workspace/tree/1da077943681bccba1876165cfd299bf7ee861fd/Internship%20Projects/Full%20Stack%20Web%20App/music_controller
I have tried both path and exact_path, 's, etc.
I also tried reviewing other questions but I didn't seem to make it work still.
homepage.js:
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RoomJoinPage from './RoomJoinPage';
import CreateRoomPage from './CreateRoomPage';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route }from 'react-router-dom';



export default class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<p>This is the homepage</p>} />

                    <Route path='/join' element={<RoomJoinPage/>} />
                    <Route path='/create' element={<CreateRoomPage/>} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

App.js:
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./homepage";
import RoomJoinPage from "./RoomJoinPage";
import CreateRoomPage from "./CreateRoomPage";

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
         <div>
            <HomePage />
         </div>
        );
    }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);

I have also added the path in the frontend url's
from django.urls import path
from .views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
    path('join', index),
    path('create', index) 
]


If you're just starting out, note to follow the newer documentation, and note that functional components (function MyCompoment(props) { ... })  is now the supported paradigm. That's to say class-based components (class MyComponent extends Component) used to be discouraged, but are actively receiving less support now.

What is your React router version?

Note that constructor is superfluous: you can omit it and the runtime will automatically call super for you with the arguments. If you were using a linter it should have told you that...

You also seem to be very confused about client-side vs traditional routing. Your react router is not going to call those endpoints in your django app.

Don't hesitate to use the console on the inspect Element to see what are the errors.
When starting a new react project, try to keep the index.js  and then work the structure of your project.
So I tried to quickly take your project structure to make a good starting point.
So we got index.js


import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);


reportWebVitals();



Then App.js


import React from "react";
import HomePage from "./components/HomePage";

function App() {
 return (
    <div>
      <HomePage />
    </div>
 );
}

export default App;



and the "components":
Homepage.js


import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import RoomJoinPage from './RoomJoinPage';
import CreateRoomPage from './CreateRoomPage';

function HomePage() {
 return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<p>This is the homepage</p>} />
        <Route path='/join' element={<RoomJoinPage />} />
        <Route path='/create' element={<CreateRoomPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
 );
}

export default HomePage;



CreateRoomPage.js


import React from 'react';

function CreateRoomPage() {
 return <div>This is create page</div>;
}

export default CreateRoomPage;



RoomJoinPage.js


import React from 'react';

function RoomJoinPage() {
 return <div>This is join page</div>;
}

export default RoomJoinPage;



There we go. You can see that we call the create and join component only in the homepage.js and not again in the app.js because app.js already calls homepage with his included imports.
With this you should access to your Join and Create page when typing /join or /create.

OP seems to expect that React Router is going to hit those url endpoints on the server, did you see the django code at the bottom of the question?
